# How to have Jekyll-Bootstrap not put "index.html" in the navigation

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm a happy [Jekyllbootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) user, however the `index.md` template is compiled to `index.html`. This is expected, but for me undesired behaviour.

When the navigation links to the homepage it uses `index.html` on the anchor. I can get around this using an nginx redirect, but I don't want to have any links on my site that I'm "fixing" using 301 redirects. I'd like it to generate the correct link in the first place.

So to be clear. I don't want jekyll to ever link to `index.html` but instead link to `/`.

Comment: Can you explain a little. Why do you need to make a redirect to index.html ?

Comment: I want the opposite. I want Jekyll to always link to my homepage (it's only linked in the nav as far as I can see) using the URL `/` and not `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. I had to set the following at the top of my `index.md` file:

```
---
layout: page
title: Home
group: navigation
permalink: /
---
```

The key part here being `permalink: /`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the variable `HOME_PATH` in `_includes/JB/setup`. By default it is `{% assign HOME_PATH = "/" %}`.

Comment: It is already set to "/", but the navigation is still output as "index.html" for "Home". I worked around this by setting the `permalink` configuration property to `/` in the index.md file.